# Magician transported to our Earth and captured by Nazis, who learn magic from him

Tags: story-identification, novel

Hi all hoping someone may know of or have an idea of who wrote this book.

The plot is that a wizard/magician who is named Gil from another world somehow ends up in our world during World War 2 and is captured and held by the Nazi occult division and is made to teach them magic that they would try using in the effort with the war. He eventually realises that they are not the good guys and bends his efforts to gain supplies and information as to where magic lines of power are strong enough near his location to allow him to use them and transport himself home to his own world. In the end, he successfully gets home.

I can't remember the author's name. I thought it was titled *Well of Echoes*, but I'm but not sure. I read the book roughly 15 years ago now (2013-14).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be the second book of the *Sun-Cross* series by Barbara Hambly, *[The Magicians of Night](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176301.The_Magicians_of_Night)*

> The two wizards, Jaldis and Rhion, had dared the dread Dark Well to answer the desperate call of a world without magic. Jaldis had not survived the dreadful Void. Now Rhion was alone in a world he could not imagine -- the world of Germany in 1940.
>
> The four would-be wizards of the Occult Bureau welcomed him to their home in Schloss Torweg. They wanted his help desperately. But they would not heed his advice against the calling up of dark magic. They needed magic to overcome the enemies they claimed were trying to conquer their fatherland. To that high mission, nothing could be neglected, however dark and ugly.
>
> They lied to him, claiming the Dark Well had been destroyed, removing his only hope of returning to Tally and his two sons. And soon he realized he was no more than a useful prisoner.
>
> But he knew the Dark Well still existed. And somehow, despite whatever they did to him, he must find a way back across the Void!

Searching for *fantasy novel magician transported to world war 2* brought me to [10 Best Alt-History World War II novels](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/10-best-world-war-ii-alt-history-books/), which mentions the *Sun-Cross* books.

Comment: I think that may be it never read any of the others wanted could never find them thanks